# How to get current html page title with javascript

Tags: javascript, title

I'm trying to get the plain html page title with javascript.

I use firefox and with

```
document.title
```

I get extra "- Mozilla Firefox" to the end of the title. I know it would be easy to get rid of this by modifying string but if they change text, use different format etc or some other browser modifies this differently I have extra text there again.

So, is there any cross browser way to get the plain  tag content with javascript? Jquery solution is ok.

Comment: In Google Chrome there's no problem. Are you sure that the content of <title> tag doesn't contain "- Mozilla Firefox"?

Comment: I do not get the vendor name in any browser with document.title, unless it is included between the title tags.

Comment: I'm sure the title does not contain "Mozilla Firefox". this is Ubuntu Box with firefox 9.0.1 (and at least one answer below got the title without the text)

Comment: DO NOT USE JQUERY FOR THIS! document.title is the correct approach and 'mozilla firefox' will for sure not be in that value - ever!

Comment: @mikkom This is also Ubuntu, FF 10, and I have never seen `" - Mozilla Firefox"` prefixed after the title in `document.title`, not even in earlier versions of FF.

Comment: @japrescott What's wrong with jQuery, if he's already using it?

Comment: @Zenexer its not about the load of the lib. Its about using jquery for something, for which javascript "was designed". Jquery is great, but in this case it just adds a shitload of cpu-cycles

Comment: Everyone: Yes, firefox with ubuntu box did add document.title did add the - mozilla firefox at the end of document.title. Iceweasel 9.0.1 did not. I have no idea why. I have quite a long experience in programming and software design (20+ years) so please, I don't need comments about what should I use or what should I not use - I just want the plain title and I got it :-)

Comment: japrescott: What you are talking about is premature optimization. That is evil and unnecessary here as the "CPU cycles" are irrelevat at such a trivial matter. We are talking about milli- or microsecond difference here. As someone else already guessed, I'm using jquery elsewhere at the program so there is no extra script loading overhead.

Comment: rob: Note that the box I used has 9.0.1, not 10. I'm at debian box now with iceweasel 9.0.1 and it does not add any text to the document.title. I have no idea why the one I tested with does and I'm 100% sure it did. This might of course have something to do with some extension I have installed (?)

Comment: Hmmm... One thing I didn't mention is that this is not a html page script but a firefox addon so it's basically a extra script that is included at the page after it's loaded with extension script. This might have something to do with the extra text if it's inserted to the title later and extension script will use different version of document than the page script would. If this is true than this might be a firefox bug.

Comment: Rando from Google here to necro this question. Let me just say that the question of whether to use `jquery` is not just a question of CPU cycles. Sometimes you don't want to bring in any (more) external dependencies. To some extent this has changes since 2012, because now `jquery` isn't the only game in town anymore. But I would really like to see more non-`jquery` answers given just because these days the code I'm working in either has no dependencies or ALL OF THEM (and `jquery` is the one that gets no respect anymore).

Answer (score 138, accepted):

One option from DOM directly:

```
$(document).find("title").text();
```

Tested only on chrome & IE9, but logically should work on all browsers.

Or more generic

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: do not use jquery for such a trivial problem.

Comment: Added same solution in standard JS

Comment: What does the [0] do here?

Comment: @munchschair since `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of elements, [0] selects the first element in that array.

Comment: or use document.title https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title

Comment: @comfytoday I agree about defaulting to `document.title`. But the question is explicitly for situations where `document.title` returns unwanted results (eg. extra characters), and the person asking the question doesn't want to parse the returned title.

Comment: @Marcus true, the question does say that. The linked MDN document however states that `document.title` "...returns the title specified in the markup", (with `<title>`) ... on some pages `document.title` could have been overwritten I guess... or it's just changed since this question was asked.

Comment: @comfytoday I agree, it's a weird case, and I'm not sure of how to duplicate the issue. Still, as you suggest, there are reasons why it could have been changed... I guess otherwise the OP wouldn't have had this problem.

Answer (score 9):

try like this

```
$('title').text();
```

Comment: Already tried. Doesn't work (returns empty string for some reason).

Comment: @mikkom: Was your `<title>` in `<head>`? Did you try it on any other versions of Firefox at the time? Did the HTML validate?

Answer (score 6):

```
$('title').text();
```

returns all the title

but if you just want the page title then use

```
document.title
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');
});
```

works for IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with plain JavaScript DOM methods.The concept is easy:

1. Retrieve `title` element from DOM.
2. Get its content using `innerHTML` or `innerText`.

So:

```
const titleElement = document.getElementsByTagName("title")
const title = titleElement.innerText

console.log(title) // The title of the HTML page.
```

To retrieve, you can use other methods such as `querySelector`, or adding an id to title, `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

To get title and save it to a constant use:

`const { title } = document;`