# JavaScript get the <title> element

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I am writing a script that will make the title tag switch messages every few seconds.

I wrote the code but when I tried to run it, I got an error here:

```
title = document.getElementByTagName("title")
```

The error I am getting says: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElementByTagName("title")')`.

The `script` tag is below the `title` tag and inside my script tag I have this to make sure the page has fully loaded before the code is ran:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //code
```

Why am I getting an error when I try to get the `title` tag?

Thank you.

Comment: "Why am I getting an error" - If you're getting an error, then *tell people what that error says* when you are asking about it!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: ```getElementsByTagName``` not ```getElementByTagName```.

Comment: Seriously? Why the vote down?

Comment: It's `getElementsByTagName` (note the s)

Comment: It's a simple question that has been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228947/how-to-get-current-html-page-title-with-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`getElementByTagName` isn't a function (unless you write one).

There is a `getElementsByTagName` function (note Elements is *plural*) which returns a node list.

It's usually simpler to just use `document.title` though (which is a string).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking into changing the title of the document, which is in the  markup,
use:

```
document.title = 'New Title';
```

Your code works with some correction, and it works in a more general case:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]='New Title';
```

However, it doesn't really change the document title, like the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

`document.title` stores the title by default, and unless you are running JavaScript on HTML that isn't from the current page, it is usually simplest to just use that.

However, the code you wanted to write in bare JavaScript was:
`document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;`

If you are already using jQuery, you can use `$(document).find('title').text();` to set your own variable.