# Get content of a <title> element in html using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page and i have it something like

`<title>this is very cool!</title>`

i would like to write a javascript function to retrieve the text in between the `<Title>` tags. I'm familiar with `getElementById` and `getElementsByName`, is there something I've missed?

thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this Answer to a similar Question on http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229043/3927116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `getElementsByTagName()` function to get element text property, try this

```
document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].text
```

Answer (score 6):

You can access it via global `document` property: [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.title)