# How to get full page title efficiently

Tags: javascript, php, title

Is there any foolproof+resource efficient way to get the title of a page using javascript and php.
So far I've tried:
1) Getting the whole code of the page and then separating the title from it by using `explode()`
2) Using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

So, I just wanted to know if there is any better way of doing this.

Comment: Sayinf the title you don't mean the tab's title? If you want this it is fairly easy.

Comment: Question is not clear about context, could you explain more about what you want achieve and code snippet.

Comment: If you mean getting a remote page, then get its html and use a DOM parser to get the `<title>` (with php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current html page title with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228947/how-to-get-current-html-page-title-with-javascript)

Comment: @Rakshit are you searching for html page title?

Comment: Yes, I want the current page's HTML page title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could the title of the page using `JavaScript` as simple as `document.title`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var title = document.title;
</script>
```

If you want to get the title of the page using `jQuery`, you could try this:

```
$(function(){
    var title = $('title').text();
})
```

**Update**

The above can be applied, if you are the "owner" of the page. If you want to get the `title` of a page given it's `url`, there is a helpful link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399332/fastest-way-to-retrieve-a-title-in-php), which addresses this problem.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in php also(foolproof+efficient).

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert(document.title);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the js solution but I also wanted a php solution

Comment: No, its just a custom made website.

Answer (score 1):

@Christos has supplied a [helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399332/fastest-way-to-retrieve-a-title-in-php) for getting the title `using file_get_content()` and the full url of the page.

There is another approach to this, using the PHP [Output Buffering Control](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). In this approach you will start the PHP page with [ob_start()](http://ob_start(%22callback%22);); then have your HTML code and then flush the output. in this scenario you you will have all the HTML code in the PHP buffer and can work on it as you like using the same regular expression as suggested in the `file_get_content()` answer.

```
<?php
    $title = NULL; // will hold the page title

    ob_start(); // start output control    
?>
<!-- HTML PAGE CODE HERE -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Page title from tag</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing 
elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa . </p>    

</body>
</html>

<?php

    // find the title in the buffer using ob_get_contents
    if (preg_match('{<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title[ ]*>}i', ob_get_contents(), $matches)) {
        $title = $matches[1];
    }

    // flush the buffer to screen
    ob_end_flush();

    // work with the title variable - check first if null
    echo '<hr/>'.$title;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`title` property of `document` object is what you need.

```
var title = document.title;
```

If you are using jQuery to bring in another page, you could do on it, `$(data).find('title').text()`