# Changing parent h1 text to reflect title of child iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, attributes, parent-child

How can I get the page title of a webpage from my `iframe` and have it displayed within the `h1` element of the header of the parent page? Thanks in advance!

My bare HTML is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>This title remains unchanged</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>This should be the title of any page loaded in the iFrame below</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content"> 
            <iframe src="http://fair-go.com/crap/cpgs/act_paramedic/index_cmg.htm" width="100%" height="640"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Assuming that the parent page is on a different URL from `fair-go.com`, then you will not be able to achieve this, as you cannot accross Cross-Domain iframe content via Javascript.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228947/how-to-get-current-html-page-title-with-javascript

Comment: It is on the same url.. I will be adding the above parent html file at the http://fair-go.com/crap/cpgs/ level.